# QR code is not working - Delegate method is not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, barcode

I have seen many threads and tutorials regarding this but nothing solved my problem. I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/) for implementing simple QR code application but code is not getting detected.In most of QR related question the issue was related to delegate methods old name. I have verified it that i am using updated delegate method but still its not working.

This is my code. Any one can please highlight which silly mistake i am doing.

```
import UIKit 
import AVFoundation

class QRScannerController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var messageLabel:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var topbar: UIView!

    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?

    let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeInterleaved2of5Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeITF14Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeDataMatrixCode] as [String]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video as the media type parameter.
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        do {
            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)

            // Initialize the captureSession object.
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

            // Set the input device on the capture session.
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

            // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

            // Start video capture.
            captureSession?.startRunning()

            // Move the message label and top bar to the front
            view.bringSubview(toFront: messageLabel)
            view.bringSubview(toFront: topbar)

            // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

            if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
                view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
                view.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
            }

        } catch {
            // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate Methods

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
            messageLabel.text = "No QR/barcode is detected"
            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        if supportedCodeTypes.contains(where: { $0 == metadataObj.type }) {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
            }
        }
    }
     }
```

> I am testing it on iPod with iOS version 9.3.5 and the code is in
>   swift 3 with xcode 8.3.2.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Where is it failing? What behavior are you having? Do you get any console message? What parts of the code are being executed (you can try that with breakpoints or prints)?

Comment: Video is properly capturing but control never goes in output  delegate method " `func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) `". And barcode doesn't even highlight with green border on screen.

Comment: Where do you actually set the delegate? I don't see it here in the provided code, and Command-F searching this page for `delegate =` provides no results

Comment: `captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)` This line is serving the purpose.

Comment: Your method signature it is not for Swift 3 it is for Swift 4  `func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on iOS 10.x `metadataOutput` is called `captureOutput`. Change the name and the signature and it should work flawlessly:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
   // func code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine now. But i am not cleared on a point. For both iOS 11 and iOS 10 support may i need to add both methods? 1. `func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection)` 2. `func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)`

Comment: No. The system already handles that for you and understands what you mean no matter if you are on iOS 11 or iOS 10. It doesn't go backwards because iOS 11 cannot know how iOS 11 is going to be. So, just the older version works fine.